# How can I solve Python 3 PIL putalpha problem?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am using **putalpha** function for my project. But I have a problem.

When I don't use the putalpha:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEoNr.png)

When I use the putalpha:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70l4T.png)

How can I solve this problem ?

Code:

```
def add_logo(pos, size=5, rotation=0, alpha=255):
    mainim = Image.open("resim.png").convert("RGB")
    logoim = Image.open("pawpink.png").convert("RGBA")
    logoim = logoim.rotate(rotation, expand=1)

    logoim.putalpha(alpha)

    #Calculate size
    width, height = mainim.size
    width = width / size
    oran = (logoim.size[0] / logoim.size[1])
    height = (width * (oran ** -1))
    logoim = logoim.resize((int(width), int(height)))

    mainim.paste(logoim, box=pozisyon_getir_resim(pos), mask=logoim)
    return mainim
```

Images:

[cat.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IO0Kh.png)

[logo.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmmGx.png)

Comment: Kindly provide your input images so we start from the same point as you!

Comment: I added the pictures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this excellent article [Watermark with PIL (Python recipe)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/362879-watermark-with-pil/)  and was able to get your program to work.

Here is my version (complete, tested):

```py
import PIL.Image
import PIL.ImageEnhance

def pozisyon_getir_resim(pos):
    return (pos, pos)

def reduce_opacity(im, opacity):
    """Returns an image with reduced opacity."""
    assert opacity >= 0 and opacity <= 1
    if im.mode != 'RGBA':
        im = im.convert('RGBA')
    else:
        im = im.copy()
    alpha = im.split()[3]
    alpha = PIL.ImageEnhance.Brightness(alpha).enhance(opacity)
    im.putalpha(alpha)
    return im

def add_logo(pos, size=5, rotation=0, alpha=255):
    mainim = PIL.Image.open("cat.png").convert("RGB")
    logoim = PIL.Image.open("logo.png").convert("RGBA")
    logoim = logoim.rotate(rotation, expand=1)

    logoim = reduce_opacity(logoim, alpha/255.0)

    # Calculate size
    width, height = mainim.size
    width = width / size
    oran = (logoim.size[0] / logoim.size[1])
    height = (width * (oran ** -1))
    logoim = logoim.resize((int(width), int(height)))

    if mainim.mode != 'RGBA':
        mainim.convert('RGBA')
    layer = PIL.Image.new('RGBA', mainim.size, (0, 0, 0, 0))
    layer.paste(logoim, pozisyon_getir_resim(pos))

    return PIL.Image.composite(layer, mainim, layer)


mainim = add_logo(32, 5, 0, 127)
mainim.save('cat_with_logo.png', 'PNG')
```

Result:
[image: cat_with_logo.png]